# Activating License managed with License Manager over C# Application doesn't work

Tags: c#, httprequest, wordpress-rest-api

I have created a wordpress site through which I want to activate licenses using my C# application with the LicenseManager plugin and RestAPI. The API uses a ConsumerKey and a ConsumerSecret for authentication. The API can be reached via a link: (example) [www.example.com/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses/activate/](http://www.example.com/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses/activate/). After .../activate/ in the link follows the license key which you want to activate. I simply add this license key in my code via a string.
This is the code I tried:

```
private async Task<bool> ActivateLicense()
    {
        string baseUrl = "http://www.example.com/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses/activate/";
        string consumerKey = "ExampleConsumerKey";
        string consumerSecret = "ExampleConsumerSecret";
        string licenseKey = "ExampleLicenceKey";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl + licenseKey);
            var authValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                                                          Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(consumerKey + ":" + consumerSecret)));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authValue;

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Request failed with status code: " + response.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course I replaced the license key, the ConsumerKey and the ConsumerSecret with my working strings.
However, when I run the code I get the following output:

> Request failed with status code: Unauthorized
>
> Activation failed

At first I was skeptical that I was using the wrong ConsumerKey, the wrong ConsumerSecret or an incorrect URL. I also suspected that maybe the API was not working.
For this reason I tested the whole thing manually.
For this I simply entered the URL in a browser and when a login window came up I entered my ConsumerKey for the username and the ConsumerSecret for the password. Thereupon I received this in my browser:

[image: Server Response after manuel API Request]

Edit:
I changed my code and added the following line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Response content: " + await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

With that I was able to get a more detailed server response:

> Request failed with status code: Unauthorized
>
> Response content:
>
> {"code":"lmfwc_rest_authentication_error","message":"Consumer key or secret is missing.","data":{"status":401}}
> Activation failed

I guess I need another way to pass my consumerKey and consumerSecret to the server, but I can't find anything online and the API documentation doesn't provide an answer either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static string SHOPAUTH = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes($"{prod_api_shop_licencemanager_clientId}:{prod_api_shop_licencemanager_secretSecret}"));
```

(...)

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", SHOPAUTH);
```

(...)